# Cannot IO in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a function to count no of times each word is repeated in a string:

```
keywords :: String -> [String]
keywords = words . map (\x -> if isAlpha x then x else ' ')

count :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
count = map (head &&& length) . group . sort

wordcount = count . keywords
```

which works perfectly.

I want to read a text file as input to this function using the IO. I did the coding like this:

```
wordcou :: IO ()
wordcou  = 
   do
    putStr "Please text file name :"
    textfile <- getLine
    text <- readFile textfile
    let result = wordcount text
    putStr result
```

The IO function is giving me an error. Can any one help me fix this error please?

error is

```
ERROR file:.\project.hs:194 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : putStr result
*** Term           : result
*** Type           : [([Char],Int)]
*** Does not match : [Char]
```

Comment: ".. is giving me an error". Could you *please* post the *exact* error message you get?

Comment: wordcount text doesn't return a String. So putStr result won't work. The type for wordcou is wrong too, it returns IO ().

Comment: ok.. i canged it.. but getting a different error.. i have updated the error in the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems:

- `wordcou` should be  of type `IO ()`, since it doesn't return anything
- `putStr` should be replaced by `print` because result is not a `String`

After these changes, your code compiles and runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add a type declaration for `wordcount`.

Look at the types and definitions of of `putStr` and `print`.
Do you see the difference?